# LINQ - Select statement on nested collection object

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class file as mentioned below:

```
public class TestA
{
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public List<TestA> TestCollection {get;set;}
}
```

above you can see type of `TestCollection` is the List of parent class.

Now I want to retrieve Names from each and every object.

I tried with `SelectMany` as shown below: but that doesn't work for me.

```
testAList.SelectMany(t => t.Name)
```

How can I achieve this ?

Here is the fiddle code: [Fiddle Code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ht0tw2)

Comment: "But that doesn't work for me" - care to be more specific? What *specifically* doesn't work? What is it doing that you don't want, or what is it not doing that you do want?

Comment: Also I find the design of this class troublesome. Why a class of type TestA should contain a list of TestA instances?

Comment: This is basically self referencing loop. Why do you want this?

Comment: Should be : testAList.Select(t => t.Name).ToList();

Comment: @jdweng: it will give me parent records only

Comment: @Justcode: I don't want this. But this is the existing code which I cant change.

Comment: @user2988458 You need to this will result in pain. *always*

Comment: @Justcode: I know and my pain has already been started. But this time I am not in a situation to change as it is a giant application.

Comment: @Steve How about a tree. Each tree node would have children that were also tree nodes. Or a management hierarchy where each person has a list of people that report to them. There are a lot of examples where this structure makes sense.

Comment: Then : testAList.TestCollection.Select(t => t.Name).ToList();

Comment: Is the results you are looking for a tree where you need a recursive method?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `testAList` is a `List<TestA>` and you want the `Name` values of the `TestA` objects inside the `TestCollection` property of every `TestA` object inside `testAList`:

```
testAList.SelectMany(x => x.TestCollection.Select(y => y.Name))
```

Or, if you want the `Name` of the objects in `testAList`:

```
testAList.Select(x => x.Name)
```

Finally, if you want ALL the names, you will need to use more than just LINQ because of the recursive nature of your class:

```
IEnumerable<string> GetNames(List<TestA> testAList)
{
    return testAList.Select(x => x.Name)
                    .Concat(testAList.SelectMany(x => GetNames(x.TestCollection)));
}

var names = GetNames(testAList);
```

Comment: I wonder which one is faster, your answer or `testAList.SelectMany(x => x.TestCollection).Select(y => y.Name)`

Comment: @Seb: Both perform the same. And regarding the recursive nature of that class: You are right, my code doesn't handle this. I am nor sure however if the OP wanted this.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: I want to retrieve name from all parent and child objects.

Comment: Perfect answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Your collection is recursive, so you need t a recursive query to get its results:

```
IEnumerable<string> GetAllNames(TestA root) {
    return GetNames(new[] {root}); // Forward to a method taking IEnumerable<T>
}
IEnumerable<string> GetAllNames(IEnumerable<TestA> tests) {
    return tests
        .Select(t => t.Name) // Names at this level
        .Concat(tests.SelectMany(t => GetAllNames(t.TestCollection))); // Names of children
}
```

However, C# offers a better approach using yield return:

```
IEnumerable<string> GetAllNames(TestA node) {
    yield return node.Name;
    foreach (var childName in node.TestCollection.SelectMany(t => GetAllNames(t))) {
        yield return childName;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the yield return approach as well and also try to avoid recursive approach if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate option that does not use linq but can provide the same result

```
IEnumerable<string> GetAllNames(TestA root) {
    return GetAllNames(new[] { root });
}

IEnumerable<string> GetAllNames(IEnumerable<TestA> tests) {
    var queue = new Queue<TestA>(tests);
    while (queue.Count > 0) {
        var current = queue.Dequeue();
        yield return current.Name;
        if (current.TestCollection != null) {
            foreach (var child in current.TestCollection) {
                queue.Enqueue(child);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above based on your fiddle would produce

```
Parent_0
Parent_1
Parent_2
Parent_3
Parent_4
Child_0_0
Child_0_1
Child_1_0
Child_1_1
Child_2_0
Child_2_1
Child_3_0
Child_3_1
Child_4_0
Child_4_1
```

If you use a stack approach

```
IEnumerable<string> GetAllNamesStack(IEnumerable<TestA> tests) {
    var stack = new Stack<TestA>(tests.Reverse());
    while (stack.Count > 0) {
        var current = stack.Pop();
        yield return current.Name;
        if (current.TestCollection != null) {
            current.TestCollection.Reverse();
            foreach (var child in current.TestCollection) {
                stack.Push(child);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output would be

```
Parent_0
Child_0_0
Child_0_1
Parent_1
Child_1_0
Child_1_1
Parent_2
Child_2_0
Child_2_1
Parent_3
Child_3_0
Child_3_1
Parent_4
Child_4_0
Child_4_1
```